# SCO OS 6 Driver for LSIL SAS1064E Raid Controller

Tags: raid, drivers, password-recovery, boot-loader

A client has an SCO OpenServer Server 6.0, that is running on an HP ProLiant Box and they lost the root password. 
Its equipped with a Doal-Core Intel Pentium Processor. They don't have any media or emergency disk anymore.

I tried to boot with the CD Rom, then "Tools", then exit to a shell, but I can’t mount the HD or the RAID, because the root fs is on a LSI Logic Raid controller MPT SAS1064E.

I found an LSIL driver for SCO OS 5.0.7 that I can load at boot time, but this version does not support this SAS RAID controller card.

Is there a driver for OS Server 5.07 for this LSIL SAS1064E RAID controller?

Or, is there a driver for OS 6.0 or for another version for SAS1064E and where can I find a boot load driver disk? 
(Since it is installed and running on that box, there must be a driver somewhere!)

What device will the root filesystem be available, mounted to? (On regular startup it is at /dev/rroot)

Any help appreciated, 
Thomas.

---

I now have installed a second SCO 6 instance on a 3rd hard disk in the same system and the same controller. I can now boot on that new instance and have root acceess there.

It runs in an intel Compaq box with an LSI Logic Corp MPT SAS RAID board SAS1064E-IR.

There are 3 disks.

In slot 4 is an ATA SATA disk that I boot from.

In slot 1 and 2 are SAS drives. They are configured to be in  a RAID configuration.

SLOT      ID            LUN        Product

4              0              0              ATA

4              1              0              LSILOGIC Volume

The new root device is /dev/root which is the ATA drive.

The LSILOGIC Volume is the old RAID volume that also contains an SCO 6 installation. 
Now I need to get access to that old installation, but I can't seem to find the correct /dev/?? to mount.

Which one would be the correct device(s) for the LSILOGIC Volume? 
If it is not there, how do I create it? mkdev…?.
And how do I mount it? Currently “mount /dev/sdxx /mnt/test” throws errors about not being a DOS drive or not being a correct device.

sdiconfig-l is 
bash-3.00# sdiconfig -l
0:0,112,0: HBA     : (mpt,1)LSI Logic 1064E 10414
   0,0,0: DISK    : ATA     WDC WD5000AAKX-61H18
   0,1,0: DISK    : LSILOGICLogical Volume  3000
1:0,2,0: HBA     : (ide,1) Generic IDE/ATAPI
   0,0,0: CDROM   : PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-118L1.02
 bash-3.00#

Thanks, T.

Comment: Linux has supported VxFS for many years, so you can probably just boot a relatively recent 32-bit Linux CD (with a reasonably complete set of modules) and rescue your data using that. Of course this machine is many years past the date it should have been decommissioned, and the business clearly did not think it was very important, so you probably won't be putting much effort into recovering it anyway.